# How set path sdk on eclipse kepler

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm try to se path of sdk android in eclipse kepler but in windows-preference-android there is only ndk and not sdk.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Got to Eclipse **Preferences**.

Place the cursor on the **Android** field not in its sub menu where you find *Build*, *DDMS*, *Editors*, *NDK*, etc.

On the right you will see **SDK Location** where you put the path of the SDK.